# In my rails app, my tests confirm the presence of error messages, but when I test as a real user I cannot see the messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's an auction app, and the functionality here is that of bidding, on a specific lot. I have setup the controller, validations in the model and the view to see error messages when form is submitted with blank value or when value is smaller than what is estipulated through a custom validation method, as you can see bellow:

```
   
    class Bid < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :lot

        validates :value, presence: { message: 'connot be blank' }

        validate :bid_value_validation, on: :create

        def bid_value_validation 
          minimum_bid_value = lot.bid_value_to_beat
          if value.present? && value < minimum_bid_value
            errors.add(:value, ' has to be greater than the minimum')
          end
        end
      end
```

The create action is configured like this:

```
    
    def create 
          @lot = Lot.find(params[:lot_id])
          @bid = Bid.new(set_params)
          @bid.user = current_user
          @bid.lot = @lot  
     
            if @bid.save
              redirect_to @lot, notice: "Bid succesfully made."
            else
              flash.now[:alert] = 'Bid could not be posted.'
              render 'new' 
            end
        end
```

And in the view (new bid view) I have setup the messages to show up like this:

```
    
    <% if @bid.errors.any? %>
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Verifique os erros abaixo:</p>
              <ul>
               <% @bid.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

Tests using rspec recognize the presence of the error messages in the front (using capybara), and when simulating in the rails console, I also can see the error messages. This is what makes this so annoying. For the css I am using bootstrap, in case anyone considers there might be a conflict of this nature.

Comment: I'm assuming the `<pre><code>` tags are not in your actual view... correct? Are they just included for this question? You don't need them.

Comment: Just removed them thanks

Comment: Since Capybara is finding the errors, this gives you confidence. I suggest you inspect the html markup in the browser's dev tools and try to find the error messages, perhaps they're off the side/bottom of the page.

Comment: I have inspected, but found nothing on the html. I suspect it might have something to do with permissions in the development.rb file, since the test simulates production envoronment. But I don´t know how to figure this out

Comment: test uses test.rb, not production.rb. But anyway, what permissions are configured in development.rb? it doesn't normally include anything that could affect view rendering.

Comment: You are right, I thought rspec simulated production, but this in not what it actually does. But still a mistery, the error messages thing. I have done the full drill trying to figure this out, including copy and paste my code in Chat GPT to see if it can find any errors, hehehe.